# Javascript - Returning a variable and a promise from a map function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to return a variable and another promise from within a promise:

```
aPromise(url)
    .then((response) => {
        return Promise.all(
        response.map((response) => {
            return {id: response.id, response: aPromise(response.url)};
        }
     })
     .then((data) => {
         // do something with data.id and data.response}
     }
```

In this example data.id is accessible but the promise data.response has not resolved. however if I return only the `apiRequest(response.url)` promise from the .map() then it does resolve.
the output of data should match =

```
[
    {id:'123', response: {...},
    {id:'456', response: {...},
    ...
]
```

Comment: You'll need another `Promise.all` inside the mapper function - or `await` for the value inside the mapper instead

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks a lot. So JS cannot resolve promises when nested inside non promise objects - only if the object itself is a promise.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Actually, This only works if returning an Array. Do you know how to do this for an object?

Comment: You'll have to return an array for the `Promise.all` to work, then you can restructure the array into the object you need.